# GDB fails with "Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 23330: (os/kern) failure " error

Tags: gdb

I installed GDB 12.1 on my mac OS Monterey 12.4. However, when I type `start` after typing `gdb main`, it shows

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 23330: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

What should I do for using gdb?